# Regression in QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation, regression

I have point rainfall and temperature values for a district and a few sample yield points for the same. How do I interpolate the yield points for the whole district wrt the rainfall and temperature? Not sure how to do this in QGIS.

Comment: We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: Have a look at GRASS v.surf.rst, see https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/de/docs/training_manual/processing/interp_contour.html -

Answer (score 2):

In the processing toolbox (Processing > Toolbox) you can find a pile of suitable tools (search for *"regression"* and *"sample"*).

You could first create a raster from the **regression** analysis (SAGA' tools ["Polynomial regression"](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.3.0/statistics_regression_2.html) or ["Regression kriging"](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.4/statistics_kriging_3.html) rsp.)

[image]

Results in some raster like

[image]

You may **sample** this with your yield points (["Set M value from raster"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#set-m-value-from-raster)):

[image]

Results in attributes of the yield points:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the above... but before going to krigging, how do we create a variogram in Qgis?

Comment: Most welcome, if the above was helpful don't hesitate to accept this answer. For the variogram thing I recommend asking this as another question.

Comment: Tried the above one but it is generating wrong values, my point data has range from 0.7 to 21 but the output from regression is giving range 3.5 to 7.8, why is this?

Comment: I'm not a mathematician, but I think it comes from the smoothing of the data set caused by the regression function. Does adding the residuals provide meaningful values? And did you cosider to use interpolation mathods that preserve your values if this is a requirement?

Comment: not sure how to proceed on this.. mind sharing some hands on or any article?

Comment: I recommend the docs on this, esp. chap. 11.10 "Further reading" https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/spatial_analysis_interpolation.html

Comment: Yes, adding up the residuals gave the meaning values. So is it that there is something wrong with the data or anywhere I went wrong?

Comment: ok so finally i ended up getting a linear equation from the variogram, i have 'a' and 'b' now. I have to use this and create a yield map in qgis which i tried in raster calculator. but the values are coming in negatives. Any idea on this?