# Second order regression in QGIS

Tags: qgis, regression

I am trying to calibrate nighttime light raster images. The data is available from 1992 to 2012 captured by different satellite and variation in the sensor too. Now in order to use the data for time series economic analysis, I need to calibrate raster images for the year wherein two different satellite provides data. As per one of the article, calibration can be done by following second-order regression.   Since I am very new in the GIS world, I don't know how to go about it. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392616/88814 or https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regression

Comment: @Babel, I tried using polynomial regression but it is asking for a point.